# Transfer data from python to nodejs using requests and socket

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io, python-requests

I try to send data from a simple python programm to a node server. But no success. That's why I ask some help.

My simple python :

```
import requests

SIGNUP_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/timer'

def submit_form():
        obj = {name:'whateever'}
        resp = requests.post(SIGNUP_URL, data = obj)        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
            submit_form()
```

my nodejs (light, I remove not concern lines) :

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const path = require('path');
const {execFile, exec, spawn} = require ('child_process');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));   

app.post('/timer', function(req, res){                 
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/status.html');
    var test = "test";
    var data = req.body;
    var info = data.name;
    io.emit('messageFromServer', { info });
    console.log('info')
});

server.listen(8000, console.log("listening to port 8000"));
```

So, when I execute my python I want transfering to the server the data "name : whatever", then I want the server write the data into the console (to be sure the data is well sent), and I all is ok, I want to emit this data to my html page...
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer :

python code :

```
import requests

SIGNUP_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/timer'

def submit_form():
        obj = {'name':'whateever'}
        resp = requests.post(SIGNUP_URL, data = obj)        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
            submit_form()
```

nodejs code :

```
app.post('/timer', function(req, res){                 
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/status.html');
    var info= req.body;
    io.emit('messageFromServer', info);
    console.log(info)
});
```

It works.